# Почему не происходит перестановка элементов в массиве, если индексы не указаны отдельными переменными?

Tags: python, list, swap

> Если пытаться совершить перестановку не используя переменные, то ничего не получится

```
array = [2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 2, 34]

index_1 = 0
index_2 = array.index(min(array[0:]))
array[0], array[array.index(min(array[0:]))] = array[array.index(min(array[0:]))], array[0]

print(array)

Output: [2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 2, 34]
```

> А если использовать переменные, то всё получается.

```
array = [2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 2, 34]

index_1 = 0
index_2 = array.index(min(array[0:]))
array[index_1], array[index_2] = array[index_2], array[index_1]

print(array)

Output: [1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 2, 8, 2, 34]
```

> Почему так происходит ?

Comment: В современном питоне можно отладить это вот так ```array[0], array[(x1:=array.index(y1:=min(array[0:])))] = array[(x2:=array.index(y2:=min(array[0:])))], array[0]```
В результате x1,y1 = 0, 1; x2, y2 = 7,1. Это происходит из-за порядка вычислений - array[(x1:=array.index(y1:=min(array[0:])))] вычисляется, когда первая перестановка уже сделана, и нулевым элементом является тот, минимальный. Соответственно 0-ой элемент записывается обратно на свое место

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Сам прочитал, что написал, по-моему непонятно. Чуть подробнее: 

1. Вычисляется правая часть присвоения ```array[array.index(min(array[0:]))], array[0]```, получается (1, 2) - это будет присваиваться левой части

2. В array[0] заносится 1

3. 2 заносится в array[array.index(min(array[0:]))], т.е. снова в 0-ой элемент, учитывая пункт 2